# Navigation drawer's fragment content and the activity's main content overlap

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm new to Android development. I'm trying to create a navigation drawer for an app using [this](http://codetheory.in/android-navigation-drawer/).

When I click on the list in the navigation bar the fragment and the previously displayed main content overlap. I tried to hide the main content using setVisibility(View.GONE). But when I press the back button, it goes to the previous activity(like it's probably supposed to). So hiding probably is not right.

What should I do  to display the fragment alone and hide the main content?

Here's the screenshot

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FFrL.jpg)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.looper.loop.PreferencesFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="fragmentlayout" />

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/uname"
                android:layout_width="292dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Enter UserName"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp">

            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pass"
                android:layout_width="292dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Enter the Password"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:password="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" Forgot Password" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

```
private void selectItemFromDrawer(int position) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContent, new PreferencesFragment()).commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mNavItems.get(position).mTitle);
    // Close the drawer
    // mainContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerPane);
}
```

Comment: I would guess you got downvoted because you've not supplied enough information to reproduce the problem. Or maybe it's the possibly offensive misspelling of "SCREENSHOT". Anyway, it sounds like you might have static content in the main layout - i.e., whichever layout contains the `mainContent` `ViewGroup` - in which case it's not going to be replaced by the `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: @MikeM. lol..sorry. thanks for pointing out the misspelling. And also thanks for the suggestion. I will see if I have some static content

Comment: @MikeM. Hi. By static content do you mean that in the mainContent there are classes, variables or methods that are declared static or do you mean something else

Comment: I meant that in the layout XML file, you might have `View`s listed inside the `mainContent` `ViewGroup`. Those `View`s aren't going to be replaced by the `FragmentTransaction`. The `Fragment` will just be added on top of them. I just answered [something similar here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757752).

Comment: Yes, I have views inside the main content. I'm trying to create a navigation drawer. How to replace the mainContent with the fragment when an item in the navigation is clicked.

Comment: Just like I said in that linked post. Put the `View`s you have in `mainContent` in their own layout, and make that the layout of its own `Fragment`, which you would load immediately upon startup. Then the `replace()` `FragmentTransaction` will work as you're expecting.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. This worked. But when I press back from the mainContent fragment I get the empty activity. And also, when I press back from the navigation bar's fragment, I don't get the mainContent fragment though I used addToBackStack(null) to the mainContent fragment.