# Replacing activity with fragment just overlays latter on top of former

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I try to replace an activity with a fragment, my app ends up rendering the fragment on top of the activity:

```
<!-- activity.xml -->
<CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coord_layout">
... stuff ...
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

here is the fragment:

```
<!-- fragment.xml -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frag_layout">
... stuff ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Main class:

```
private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    Fragment f = fragment.newInstance();

    FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.coord_layout, f).commit();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentTransaction`s deal only with (dynamically created) `Fragment`s. Any `View`s within the container `ViewGroup` you're using to hold the `Fragment` are not affected by a `replace()`. That is, the `Fragment` will just be added on top of them. If you want to completely replace the existing layout, you should replace the `CoordinatorLayout` in your `activity.xml` with an empty `ViewGroup` - usually a `FrameLayout` - and use the `CoordinatorLayout` as the layout for another `Fragment` that you can load upon startup, which can then be swapped out accordingly with your `FragmentTransaction`.